# Reuse Cursor Declaration in postgres

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, cursor, postgresql-8.4

Is there a way to reuse the cursor declaration in postgres.

For example : 
I have a function like below, I am trying to use the declaration of curs1 for curs2 is it possible ?

```
create or replace function vin_temp_test(k date,x varchar) RETURNS numeric[] AS $$
declare
curs1 CURSOR FOR select prod_name,sum(item_val) sum_value from temp_table group by prod_name;
curs2 cursor curs1;

begin
null
end;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly it is not possible

- but you can simplify code by using views
- you can use dynamic unbound queries

  ```
  DECLARE 
    c1 refcursor;
    c2 refcursor;
    sqlstr text;
  BEGIN
    sqlstr := 'SELECT ... ';
    OPEN c1 FOR EXECUTE sqlstr;
    OPEN c2 FOR EXECUTE sqlstr;
  ```

Important question is - what do you mean 'reuse a cursor'"?

Maybe you can use scrollable cursor with possible reset

There is a statement MOVE

```
MOVE FIRST IN curs1 -- reset cursor curs1
```

see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-cursors.html